# Model and Modeling

Tags: self-study, modeling, references, stochastic-processes, model

[model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/model/info) and [modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/modeling/info) seem identical to me. Aren't those really same ? (or is there any flaws so that they are two different tags.)

And in `model` tag, it is written that there is a distinct element of $P$ (probability) which generates the observed data. Though statistical model involves a random error term ($\epsilon$), will I be able to generate the same observed data for a certain probability ?

And in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model), it is written that

> A statistical model embodies a set of assumptions concerning the generation of the observed data, and similar data from a larger population.

When should i get the observed data and when should i get similar data ? For different probabilities or only one probability can generates different set of data , as statistical model involves random error term ?

Can i see it empirically ?

Comment: The tag descriptions make them seem the same, unfortunately. I'd have said they were *quite* different; one is for questions related to a model (a noun), while the other is for questions related to the process of *modelling* - of arriving at a model (a verb). The destination and the journey are different! [However, if your question is mainly about possible tag overlap it belongs on meta.stats.stackexchange.] I can't figure out what the rest of your question is even asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Glen_b I wanted to mean by the rest of the question is that can i generate the same data from a statistical model ? I doubt, because this is not deterministic model.

Comment: @Glen_b Can i be referred of an example of `modeling` please? What are the steps of modeling ? How to arrive at a model(destination) from data ?

Comment: Questions of the form "help me come up with a model for this" (like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134197/model-suggestion-for-temporarily-broken-device)) or "How do I choose which predictors to include in my model?" (like [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134648/finding-significant-predictors-of-psychiatric-readmissions)) are `modeling` questions. Your 2nd and 3rd questions there are *examples* of modeling questions, but they're too broad for a question in comments -- indeed, I think maybe even too broad for either of them posted as a question in their own right